# Unit tests failing only on the build server

Tags: c#, .net, spring

It throws an exception that is something like this:

```
Initialization method MyAssemblyA.Initialize threw exception. 
Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: 

Error thrown by a dependency of object 'messageSource' defined in 'assembly    
[MyOtherAssembly.Test, Version=1.1.1016.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], 
resource [MyOtherAssembly.context.xml] 

line 256' : Initialization of object failed : Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssemblyB' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I don't know exactly why, but a lot of the unit tests are failing only on the build server and the exception that is thrown is something similar to what I wrote above.

In my context.xml I have something like this:

```
    <object name="messageSource" type="Spring.Context.Support.ResourceSetMessageSource, Spring.Core">
    <property name="resourceManagers">
      <list>
        <ref object="resMgrCoreServiceErrors"/>
        <ref object="resMgrPersonnelErrors"/>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>

  <object name="resMgrCoreServiceErrors"
          type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ResourceManagerFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
    <property name="baseName" value="MyOtherAssembly.Resources.ErrorRes"/>
    <property name="assemblyName" value="MyOtherAssembly"/>
  </object>

  <object name="resMgrPersonnelErrors"
          type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.ResourceManagerFactoryObject, Spring.Core">
    <property name="baseName" value="MyOtherAssemblyB.Resources.ErrorRes"/>
    <property name="assemblyName" value="MyOtherAssemblyB"/>
  </object>
```

where ErrorRes is a resource file (.resx).

Please help, any suggestions are welcomed !

Comment: Do you compile your code before you run Unitests on the build server?

Answer (score 1):

are all of the dependencies of MyAssemblyB either installed in the gac or in the bin?  has to be something in that vein.

Comment: It seems that all referenced assemblies are copied to the bin folder.

Comment: Are the reference paths to the assemblies correct? You might need to re-add you references from the bin folder. Also double check that the assemblies are being copied to the output directory.

Comment: Maybe has something to do with the context.xml configuration, I will update my question.